# WeekOfDay different for en_US locale then en_UK, de_DE

Tags: swift, date, locale, swift5

I am showing week of the year in my app and users can choose first day of week as well as German or English localisation. I noticed a weird difference in the week of year when English is chosen.

Can someone explain what's going wrong? I checked if US has different numbering of some sort, but the only difference is, that the first day of the week is Sunday for US instead of Monday...

```
import UIKit

func getCalForId(_ identifier: String, andLocale locale: String) -> Calendar {
    var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    cal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: identifier)!
    cal.locale = Locale(identifier: locale)
    
    return cal
}

func GetDateByString(_ value: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
    
    return dateFormatter.date(from: value)!
}

let calDE_Berlin = getCalForId("Europe/Berlin", andLocale: "de_DE")
var calUS_Chicago = getCalForId("America/Chicago", andLocale: "en_US")
var calUS_Berlin = getCalForId("Europe/Berlin", andLocale: "en_US")
let calUK_Berlin = getCalForId("Europe/Berlin", andLocale: "en_UK")
        
let date = GetDateByString("5 5 2022 18:45:32 +0200")

let weekDE_Berlin = calDE_Berlin.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: date).weekOfYear!
let weekUS_Chicago = calUS_Chicago.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: date).weekOfYear!
let weekUS_Berlin = calUS_Berlin.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: date).weekOfYear!
let weekUK_Berlin = calUK_Berlin.dateComponents([.weekOfYear], from: date).weekOfYear!

print(calDE_Berlin.firstWeekday)            // 2
print(calDE_Berlin.minimumDaysInFirstWeek)  // 4
print(calUS_Chicago.firstWeekday)           // 1
print(calUS_Chicago.minimumDaysInFirstWeek) // 1
print(calUS_Berlin.firstWeekday)            // 1
print(calUS_Berlin.minimumDaysInFirstWeek)  // 1
print(calUK_Berlin.firstWeekday)            // 2
print(calUK_Berlin.minimumDaysInFirstWeek)  // 4

print(weekDE_Berlin)  // 18
print(weekUS_Chicago) // 19
print(weekUS_Berlin)  // 19
print(weekUK_Berlin)  // 18
```

Thanks advance

Regards

**EDIT**
Added the output for `minimumDaysInFirstWeek`. Seems only to be different for Germany. But it doesn't explain, why the en_US locale based calendar is outputting week of year 19.

Comment: check `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` property of calendar [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW10)

Comment: See my edit, the `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` is different for Germany but still I don't understand by the en_US locale produces week of year 19 :(

Comment: you forgot to print cal*UK*, which I suppose will be 4, check first dates of January 2022 - it is Saturday and Sunday, so US calendar suppose that it is week 1, but it is not enough for European calendar, so it starts week 1 from January 3rd, this is why week number is smaller by 1

Comment: yeah just saw it and edit the post. Still wondering why some websites show 18 for the current us week, e.g.: https://savvytime.com/current-week
Are there differences in US by region maybe?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160311-00/?p=93144

Comment: and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151112-00/?p=92121 - so swift is correct, it is week 19 in us and 18 in europe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Iłya Bursov I understand the "issue" now.
I find it still very confusing, that most websites are showing week 18 for US where in fact its 19 (by format, locale: en_US). On the other hand, if US is not really using them, its also understandable, that it doesn't matter too much / is different per page :D

As a "solution" this post helped understanding:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151112-00/?p=92121